What is the "php=value" parameter used for in the 'symfony new' console command?
The output from symfony help new gives:
Description:
  Create a new Symfony project

Usage:
  symfony local:new [options] [--] [<directory>]

Arguments:
  directory  Directory of the project to create


Options:
  --dir=value      Project directory
  --version=value  The version of the Symfony skeleton (a version or one of "lts", "stable", "next", or "previous")
  --full           Use github.com/symfony/website-skeleton (deprecated, use --webapp instead)
  --demo           Use github.com/symfony/demo
  --webapp         Add the webapp pack to get a fully configured web project
  --api            Add the api pack to get a fully configured api project
  --book           Clone the Symfony: The Fast Track book project
  --docker         Enable Docker support
  --no-git         Do not initialize Git
  --upsun          Initialize Upsun configuration
  --cloud          Initialize Platform.sh configuration
  --debug          Display commands output
  --php=value      PHP version to use

What does the --php=value parameter do?
"PHP version to use" means what, exactly? Use where, and when?
Are these options documented in more detail online somewhere?

I'd expect them to be explained in more detail at the symfony web site.

I think it's used by symfony php -r "...". See https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/symfony_server.html#running-commands-with-different-php-versions

I also would expect them to be explained in more detail at the symfony web site but so far I cannot find this. But thank you for your suggestion of symfony php command as a use case for this.

Basically, the only thing this option does is to create the file .php-version and populate it with your chosen value.
That value will subsequently be used by the Symfony CLI to choose a different PHP runtime to execute commands, as described here.
This PHP version will be used when running commands through the Symfony CLI wrapper (e.g. symfony console foo:bar), or even (as far as I can tell), as a runtime when using the Symfony CLI built-in server.

Thank you. I notice that .php-version is not generated when you pass the --cloud option to symfony new. Is this by design, or might it be a bug ?

Might be a bug. Not sure, I don't use the "cloud" thing.
